# View not loading in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here's my "Login.php" controller  code :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->err_msg_model = $this->config->item('err_msg_model');
    $this->err_code = $this->config->item('err_code_model');
    $this->load->helper('form');
}

public function index() {
    include_once 'Session.php';
    $this->load->view('login/vlogin');
}
```

And here my index code :

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('login');?>">Login</a></li>
```

I already add vlogin.php to my views>login>vlogin.php

Idk why, but i cant load the view somehow.

Comment: Note: You have loaded session wrong http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#initializing-a-session

Comment: Also have you tried with url having index.php `http://localhost/yourproject/index.php/login` If the url shows IP address then you have not set your base_url in config.php

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Hi, I can access it by http://localhost/yisc/index.php/login.html , whats wrong with my setting ?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 about the session, i actually a newbie in codeigniter, i'll try to seek for guidance about session later in youtube, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: My I ask why it is .html?  `http://localhost/yo‌​urproject/index.php/l‌​ogin`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 i configure url suffix for that : `$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';`

Comment: What is the error say?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 there's no error, i mean.. if i use `http://localhost/yisc/login.html` , its not working, but when i use `http://localhost/yisc/index.php‌​/l‌​ogin` its work. I want to make the url look like `http://localhost/yisc/login.html` , without index.php

Comment: OMG , i find the solution !
I forgot to setting .htaccess file ! 

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update setting on .htaccess file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

After add that on htaccess file, everything works fine !

Thanks to @wolfgang1983